# C++: Member function call forwarding using variadic data structure

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I am trying to create a class (similar to `std::tuple`) which can hold a variable number of references to objects of different type and which can forward a call to a specific member function to all of its constituents. Here is an example:

```cpp
// g++ Test7.C -std=c++17 -o Test7

#include <iostream>

struct P1 { void operator()(void) const { std::cout<<"P1 "; } };
struct P2 { void operator()(void) const { std::cout<<"P2 "; } };
struct P3 { void operator()(void) const { std::cout<<"P3 "; } };

template <class... EmitterList> struct Emitters 
{
 inline void operator()(void) const { std::cout<<std::endl; }
};

template <class Emitter, class... EmitterList>
class Emitters<Emitter,  EmitterList...> : public Emitters<EmitterList...>
{
public:
 using Base = Emitters<EmitterList...>;

 Emitters(const Emitter & e, const EmitterList & ... eList)
  : emitter(e), Base(eList...) {}

 inline void operator()(void) const { emitter(); this->Base::operator()(); }
private:
 const Emitter & emitter;
};

int main(void)
{
 P1 p1;
 P2 p2;
 P3 p3;
 Emitters e0;           e0(); // works
 //Emitters e1{p1};       e1(); // does not work
 //Emitters e2{p1,p2};    e2(); // does not work
 //Emitters e3{p1,p2,p3}; e3(); // does not work
 return 0;
}
```

The expectation is that `e1()` would output "P1 \n" (calls `p1()`), `e2()` would output "P1 P2 \n" (calls `p1(); p2()`), and `e3()` would output "P1 P2 P3 \n" (calls `p1(); p2(); p3();`). But something is not right in the code: it compiles for `e0` but not for the other cases. Could you please help me to understand what I am doing not right here and how to fix it?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do [partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization), and you're close. Rather than this

```
template <class... EmitterList> struct Emitters 
{
 inline void operator()(void) const { std::cout<<std::endl; }
};
```

Consider

```
template <class... Ts>
struct Emitters;

template <>
struct Emitters<> {
  void operator()(void) const { std::cout<<std::endl; }
};

template <class Emitter, class... EmitterList>
class Emitters<Emitter,  EmitterList...> : public Emitters<EmitterList...>
{
  // Unmodified from your example ...
}
```

The first declaration here says "there's a thing called `Emitters`, but I'm not telling you what it is yet". It's an incomplete type definition. Then we define *two cases*: one with `Emitters<>` (the empty, base case), and one (the recursive case) for when we have at least one argument.

These classes will compile now, but they're inconvenient to use. Due to complexities in the language, constructor calls aren't as good as inferring template arguments as regular functions. So a line like this

```
Emitters e1{p1};
```

isn't good enough. We *could* be explicit

```
Emitters<P1> e1{p1};
```

but that's just a pointless level of verbosity. Instead, we can look to `std::tuple`, which has the same problem. The standard library defines a function [`std::make_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple), which does nothing but call the tuple constructor. But since it's an ordinary function, we get template argument deduction.

```
template <typename... Ts>
Emitters<Ts...> make_emitters(const Ts&... args) {
  return Emitters<Ts...>(args...);
}
```

Now we can make instances without specifying template arguments

```
Emitters e0 = make_emitters();         e0();
Emitters e1 = make_emitters(p1);       e1();
Emitters e2 = make_emitters(p1,p2);    e2();
Emitters e3 = make_emitters(p1,p2,p3); e3();
```

Now your example should work as intended.

One final note about your constructor. You should always list the base class constructor first, before any fields. Compiling with `-Wall` will warn you about this. The compiler is internally reordering them for you, so it's best practice to put them in the right order to begin with. Rather than

```
Emitters(const Emitter & e, const EmitterList & ... eList)
 : emitter(e), Base(eList...) {}
```

consider

```
Emitters(const Emitter & e, const EmitterList & ... eList)
 : Base(eList...), emitter(e) {} // Note: Base and emitter are switched
```

---

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct P1 {
  void operator()(void) const {
    std::cout << "P1 ";
  }
};
struct P2 {
  void operator()(void) const {
    std::cout << "P2 ";
  }
};
struct P3 {
  void operator()(void) const {
    std::cout << "P3 ";
  }
};

template <class... Ts>
struct Emitters;

template <>
struct Emitters<> {
  void operator()(void) const {
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
};

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct Emitters<T,  Ts...> : public Emitters<Ts...> {
public:
  using Base = Emitters<Ts...>;

  Emitters(const T& e, const Ts&... eList)
    : Base(eList...), emitter(e) {}

  void operator()(void) const {
    emitter();
    this->Base::operator()();
  }

private:
  const T& emitter;
};

template <typename... Ts>
Emitters<Ts...> make_emitters(const Ts&... args) {
  return Emitters<Ts...>(args...);
}

int main(void) {
  P1 p1;
  P2 p2;
  P3 p3;
  Emitters e0 = make_emitters();         e0();
  Emitters e1 = make_emitters(p1);       e1();
  Emitters e2 = make_emitters(p1,p2);    e2();
  Emitters e3 = make_emitters(p1,p2,p3); e3();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is great, but you don't actually need any of these changes. The partial specialisation cleanup is nice and elegant, I would suggest using it, but your original code works too. And the `make_...` functions are clunky and mostly unneeded in modern C++. What you need is a deduction guide:

```
template <typename ... P>
Emitters(const P& ... ) -> Emitters<P...>;
```

[That's it](https://godbolt.org/z/Th5386ffW).